# Google instant preview doesn't make an ajax resquest! How is that possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebug, preview

This new feature in google called google instant preview (where you click the magnifying glass) that shows a snapshot of the page doesn't produce any ajax request or such as far as firebug can see. How is that possible? Is there another magic way of retrieving content without using an XMLHttpRequest (ActiveX for for the slow people)

Comment: No call on the website itself , its a image. No ajax call needed.

Comment: Granted it is an image however it's an image from a base64 location. Do you mean to tell me that each page returns with all of the image data with it? That would certainly slow down a page with 100 results per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The robot which collects the page has a "Google Web Preview" user agent. You could serve a version which doesn't show the popup when that user agent visits.

Comment: Doesn't it marked as cloaking? http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing numerous Ajax calls to http://clients1.google.com/webpagethumbnail in Firebug. Do you have the net panel properly enabled?